# Script to wipe out every Vertex color

Tags: scripting, source-code, encoding

Please can somebody help me with a script that wipes out the vertex color attribute from every mesh in the scene? I need to get rid of them so when I export to .gltf the textures won't get multiplied by the vertex colors. It happens that almost all my meshes have vertex colors on them.

Comment: You can disable the "Data > Mesh > Vertex Colors" options in the export window when you export to glTF instead. Does that work for you?

Comment: Oh damn, didn't spot that! Thanks!